# Jupyter how to plot 2 dfs next to each other

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I tried to look a couple SO's on plotting 2 plots next to each other but I couldnt find one that worked in my case. Most of the cases involves understanding how subplot works. Which I'm hoping someone can explain here.

Here are my 2 distinct plots on 2 different rows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import six
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Size = pd.read_sql("select...".sort_values(['date'],ascending=True)
```

[image]

```
Cap = pd.read_sql("select...".sort_values(['date'],ascending=True)
```

[image]

What I would like to end up is this:
[image]

I'm pretty sure from what I've been reading I need to make these into subplots then I can put them on the same row. Not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `subplots` command is the easiest way to set that up.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4))  # 1 row, 2 columns
df1.plot(..., ax=ax1)
df2.plot(..., ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()  # Optional ... often improves the layout
```

Comment: That works pretty good but it makes both of my plots not very wide. So I tried to change the fig size on both but its ignored . For example d.plot(x='date', figsize=(6,4),rot=90, ax=ax1) no matter what I do to the 6,4 my plots still look the same

Comment: So it looks like I can make them both larger if I change both. But if I change just one df's figsize then neither scale.

Comment: Set figsize in the subplots call. See the updated version. If you want your plots to be different sizes, you'll need to use one of the `gridspec` variants (probably a separate question)